# Does zend disk cache get deleted after ttl has expired?

Tags: php, zend-framework, caching

Following zend_disk_cache_store [documentation](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-IBMi/content/zend_data_cache_-_php_api.htm#function-zend_disk_cache_store) about the last parameter: "The Data Cache keeps objects in the cache as long as the TTL is not expired. Once the TTL is expired, the object is removed from the cache. The default value is 0."

The documentation does not explicitly say if the data is removed from disk or just ignored by zend. From my testings, it does not remove from disk. Is there any resource on zend to make sure the cache is removed from disk?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the principle of ttl, is that once the ttl time has expired, the cache is updated.

Answer (score 0):

The Data Cache Lock-On-Expire feature reduces the load spike of a busy application by guaranteeing that an application gathers an expired piece from the data source only once, and by avoiding a situation where multiple PHP processes simultaneously detect that the data in the cache has expired, and repeatedly run high-cost operations.

How does it work?

When a stored Data Cache entry expires, the following process takes place:

1. The first attempt to fetch it will receive a 'false' response.
2. All subsequent requests will be receiving the expired object stored in the Data Cache for the duration of 120 seconds.
3. During this time period, the php script that received the 'false' response generates an updated data entry and stores it in the Data Cache with the same key.
4. As soon as the updated data entry is created, it is returned to the subsequent fetching requests.
5. If this does not occur within the time period of 120 seconds, the entire process (1-4) will repeat itself.

More here:
http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server/zend-server.htm#working_with_the_data_cache.htm